# Is SE generating popups now?

Tags: bug

I got this popup for the second time now. (This time by crypt SE)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't look like anything we would serve.

If you are browsing over http, try using https to see if that happens again. I suspect shenanigans by your ISP or someone between you and us.

Comment: Sure! I'll try. Sadly it's not reproducible everytime so I can't say for sure if it works.